# how to import npm package in my laravel 7 project

Tags: php, laravel, npm, package, laravel-7

Where i can import this code

> const mykad = require('mykad')

from [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mykad) in to my **laravel 7** project. and how to code in blade in input form.

Answer (score 0):

You can include JS file from node_modules to your app by requiring them at your resource level app.js

`path = app\resources\js\app.js`

like this:

`const mykad = require('mykad')`

and then run in terminal

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: okay thnks. and what can i put in my blade in my input form

Comment: need to create vue components if you are using vue, you know the format `export default`

Comment: i'm not using vue

Comment: [Ikmal Mohd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14696551/ikmal-mohd) After running the command `npm run dev` it will create an app.js file in your public folder. The default path to public js will be `{{asset('js/'app.js'}}`, that's how you can use it into blade